# Redis known-replica vs known-slave

Tags: redis, redis-sentinel, redis-server

What is the difference between `known-replica` and `known-slave` configuration parameters?

I have updated redis version from 3.X to 6.X and now I have both in configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As described [here](https://github.com/redis/redis/issues/5335), Redis decided to deprecate use of the word "slave" and replace it with alternative terms whenever it was  possible to do so without harming backwards compatibility.

So these terms are synonyms, as you can see in the [source code](https://github.com/redis/redis/blob/1eb4baa5b8e76adc337ae9fab49acc2585a0cdd0/src/sentinel.c#L1966).

When you have multiple values of the same command in a configuration file, as you now do, the last-processed command is what gets used.

Comment: Thanks, but I also figured that there might be some issues with redis servers starting due to multiple definitions of same slave/replica so I have removed known-slave so that everything works as intended